# How to make database instance set in func main() available to other packages?

Tags: go, sqlite

I’m writing my first go web app and I have the following structure:

```
.
├── main.go
├── model
│   ├── model.go
│   └── book.go
├── route
│   └── route.go
└── view
    └── view.go
```

**/main.go** is where my **main()** is located. In that file I also defined a  variable Env where I’ll keep the instance of my database (at least that’s the plan).

In **/main.go** I do

```
import "project/view"

type Env struct {
    db models.Collection
}

// rest of the code

func main() {
    db, err := models.NewDB()
    // etc
    MyEnv := &Env{db}
    // etc
}
```

But the thing is that in **/view/view.go** I need to call methods defined in **/model/book.go** and I thought the way to do that was through the *MyEnv.db* instance but of course I get an error:

view/view.go:13:14: undefined: Env

^^ Any help to solve that problem would be appreciated or any lead on how to better structure my project. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a name (variable, type, etc.) from another package, you need to `import` that package, e.g. with `import "view"` you could do `view.Something` in your main package.

Now you cannot import a main package, this means that your `view` package cannot import `main` to call `main.Env`. So you have to use another way, some possibilities are:

1. Put the `Env` type in the `view` package and then in your `main` package just declare a `var myEnv = view.Env{}`.
2. Put the `Env` type in its own package `env` which you then import in both `view` and `main`
3. Instead of using a concrete type `Env` you could use an `interface` type in the `view` package. This type should only expose the functions that you need from it. Then you can implement that type in your `main` package and pass an instance of that to `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Define it on a top level of you code on main

```
var MyEnv Env

 func main(){
     MyEnv = &Env{}

  }
```